# What is a proper way to create component in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

What is right way to create custom template in `Nativescript`?

For example I have `XML` structure like:

```
     <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" alignItems = "stretch">
        <Border  borderWidth="1" borderColor="#000000">
        <FlexboxLayout height="60">
            <Button cssClass="sdk-button" col="0" text="initSDK" tap="{{initSdk}}" flexGrow="1"/>

            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="data-wrapper" flexGrow="3" paddingLeft="20">
                <Label text="{{ initSdkResponse }}" class="data_wrapper-label" textWrap="true"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
        </Border>
    </FlexboxLayout>
```

I want to create component with above mentioned structure, named `MyItem` and use it as follow:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
      <MyItem buttonName="click1"
              buttonAction="onClick1()"
              labelText="xxxxxxx1"
      ></MyItem>

      <MyItem buttonName="click2"
              buttonAction="onClick2()"
              labelText="xxxxxxx2"
      ></MyItem>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: In your cases you might want to think about of creating your own UI plugin  - https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin#xml-ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find these resources helpful:

https://moduscreate.com/custom-components-in-nativescript/

http://blog.bradleygore.com/2016/03/12/custom-nativescript-components/

http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#custom-components